# How to make a jenkins call to retrieve the job details every 'X' minutes in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, jenkins, cron, cron-task

What I'm up to is to get the jenkins job details and store it in mongo DB every "X" minutes. I have to make an `HTTP.call(JenkinsURL)` which I know how to do. My problem is calling it for specific intervals.

```
buildDetails=HTTP.call('GET',buildURL);
```

`buildURL` has the Jenkins job URL. I found this [link](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) which gives an overview of the code for my problem, but I don't know how and where i should place these code to get it working. I tried all possibility.

Is there any method in meteor which can make this possible to run a specific code to be run for every X min??

Comment: *I tried all possibilities* - Do explain. You can use ```Meteor.setInterval()``` to run something every X interval of time.

Comment: I mean that i have tried all the combination of the code in the link which i have specified. I tried the Meteor.setInterval(), it works as it defined, but when i refresh and navigate to other page it will stop executing the interval() code.

Comment: That would be because you're calling it from the client. Is there any specific reason to do it from the client? Normally, for your use case, it should be called from the server don't you think?

Comment: I'm not calling it from client, i want to run those set of commands from server and should be running on backgroud..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there any method in meteor which can make this possible to run a specific code to be run for every X min??*

Yes, there is.

[`Meteor.setInterval`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setInterval) that can be used to do something repetitively every X interval of time.

You can put your HTTP call within it on the server. Eg:

```
Meteor.startup({function(){

    var timerID = Meteor.setInterval(function(){
                     buildDetails=HTTP.call('GET',buildURL);
                     // and other things
                     }, 60000) //60000ms = 1 min
                 }
});
```

When you want to stop the timer function, simply call [`Meteor.clearInterval`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-clearInterval)

```
Meteor.clearInterval(timerID);
```

Comment: getting error like= "unexpected , expected , "  at the  Meteor.setInterval(getAndStore(){

Comment: My bad. I had the wrong syntax for ```getAndStore()```. It should just be a ```function```. I've fixed it. Also, this is meant to work exactly like you want it to. I'm not sure why you a page refresh makes this to stop working. It should ideally continue to work until the application is shut down, or you explicitly call ```clearInterval```

Comment: Tq, it's working as i expected, but the problem is that when other server side code(helpers,events and other function) executes, getAndStore() will wait till other executes and if i have more number of HTTP.call() the interval will start from initial count. Is there any other way to make it run in background like thread? pls provide any reference if u know..

Comment: helpers and events are not server side code. You can try wrap the ```setInterval``` within```meteor.onStartup()```  and possible place it in ```/server/lib/``` so that it runs as soon as the app is running.

Comment: ohh..sry i know helpers and events on client side, i mean other meteor.methods() functions. And is there any way we can run this code in seperate thread like in other programming languages?